# Angular toggle class on two divs

Tags: angularjs, class, toggle

I have:

```
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="main_menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when click on .btn to toggle 'class1' on him and to toggle 'class2' on .main_menu

Comment: Lets say if class1 is not set on btn, so then have to be set and If is set have to be removed. The same is for main_menu and class2

Comment: Ok i misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn" ng-class="{'class1': btnClicked}" ng-click="btnClicked = !btnClicked"></div>
<div class="main_menu" ng-class="{'class2': btnClicked}">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: He want two different toggle, for class1 and class2. add a btnClicked2

Comment: Can you explain? Now only class1 has toggle on btn when click. main_menu has no toggle with class2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/bnd40se5/4/

The html would be something like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggle()" class="btn" ng-class="{'added-btn-class' : toggleCheck}">Toggle classes</button>
  <div class="main_menu" ng-class="{'added-menu-class' : toggleCheck}">
    <ul>
      <li>Toggle check : {{toggleCheck}}</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.toggleCheck = false;
      $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.toggleCheck = !$scope.toggleCheck;
      }
    }
```

**NOTE:** 
Depending on your project and situation this could vary, proper scope would need to be used etc etc, but for now, this simple example should push you in the right direction.